# How to delay 15 minutes? 5 minutes restriction

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Here is a very simple program that I wrote:

```
function () {
    var app = SpreadsheetApp ;
    var tableur = app.getActiveSpreadsheet() ;
    var feuille = tableur.getActiveSheet();
    var now = new Date();
    Utilities.sleep(900000)  
    feuille.getRange("A1000").setValue(now);
    feuille.getRange("B1000:O1000").setValue("1000000");
    feuille.getRange("P1000").setValue("Prudent"); 
    feuille.getRange("Q1000").setValue("10"); 
    feuille.getRange("R1000").setValue("10"); 
    feuille.getRange("S1000").setValue("NON"); 
}
```

However, I want the code to wait 15 minutes before it continues. Google has a restriction of 5 minutes, which is why I read a lot about this issue but I couldn't find any solution. I actually used `Utilities.sleep (900000)` but it doesn't work.

I appeal to your kindness to explain to a beginner like me how to circumvent the restriction if ever this is possible! :)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var triggerTime = new Date();
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty("lastTrigger", triggerTime);
}

function doSomething() {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var lastTrigger = new Date(scriptProperties.getProperty("lastTrigger"));
  var lastTriggerUnix = lastTrigger.getTime() / 1000; // using unix time for a more straightforward time comparison
  var nowUnix = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
  var FIFTEEN_MINUTES = 15 * 60;
  if ((nowUnix - lastTriggerUnix) >= FIFTEEN_MINUTES) {
    scriptProperties.deleteProperty("lastTrigger");
    var app = SpreadsheetApp ;
    var tableur = app.getActiveSpreadsheet() ;
    var feuille = tableur.getSheetByName("Réponses"); // getActiveSheet() can yield unexpected results
    var app = SpreadsheetApp ;
    var now = new Date()
  feuille.getRange("A10").setValue(now);
  feuille.getRange("B10:O10").setValue("1000000");
  feuille.getRange("P10").setValue("Prudent"); 
  feuille.getRange("Q10").setValue("10"); 
  feuille.getRange("R10").setValue("10"); 
  feuille.getRange("S10").setValue("NON"); 
  }
}
```

Is there something I forgot?

Comment: 1) you should add the the google-app-script tag to your question
2) have you tried to call it more than once, or loop it?
Utilities.sleep(300000) 
Utilities.sleep(300000) 
Utilities.sleep(300000)

Comment: 3) you could have added the reference to the restriction you found, which makes it easier to verify it: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds

Comment: 1) Done, thank you
2) Just tried --> Authorized execution time exceeded
3) https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas --> Script runtime 6 min / execution

Comment: How about using trigger? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger

Comment: Does it need to be *exactly* 15 minutes? Or can it be 15.5 minutes, maybe 14-16 minute intervals?

Comment: The trigger is : after modification of the Spreadsheet. 
And then wait 15 minutes and set values.
Nothing seems to work like that in the triggers

Comment: It doesn't need to be exactly 15 minutes. It could be like 10min-20min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the new information that you want the `doSomething()` script to run roughly 15 minutes after the spreadsheet was last edited, here's my modification, but using the same general principle.

Create an `onEdit()` simple trigger that saves the edit time to the Properties Service (this is done by simply including the `onEdit` function, which [Google interprets automatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#getting_started)). Separately, create a manual trigger to run the `doSomething()` function every 5 minutes or so. When that function runs, it will check the last edit time and execute your desired actions if the difference between the last edit and now is greater than or equal to your desired length.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var triggerTime = new Date();
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty("lastTrigger", triggerTime);
}

function doSomething() {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var lastTrigger = new Date(scriptProperties.getProperty("lastTrigger"));
  var lastTriggerUnix = lastTrigger.getTime() / 1000; // using unix time for a more straightforward time comparison
  var nowUnix = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
  var FIFTEEN_MINUTES = 15 * 60;
  if ((nowUnix - lastTriggerUnix) >= FIFTEEN_MINUTES) {
    scriptProperties.deleteProperty("lastTrigger");
    // Do what you need to do here
  }
}
```

---

You should use the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) to save `now`, then use a [Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to run the script every 15 minutes. (The first time you run it, the timings might be slightly off.)

```
function doSomething() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp ;
  var tableur = app.getActiveSpreadsheet() ;
  var feuille = tableur.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // getActiveSheet() can yield unexpected results
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var storedNow = scriptProperties.getProperty("now") || new Date(); // Get the stored time. If it doesn't exist, create a new one.
  var now = new Date(storedNow); // The value is stored as a String in the Properties Service, so convert to Date.
  feuille.getRange("A10").setValue(now);
  feuille.getRange("B10:O10").setValue("1000000");
  feuille.getRange("P10").setValue("Prudent"); 
  feuille.getRange("Q10").setValue("10"); 
  feuille.getRange("R10").setValue("10"); 
  feuille.getRange("S10").setValue("NON"); 
  now = new Date(); // Create a new date to be used when the function runs again
  scriptProperties.setProperty("now", now); // Save the new date
}
```

As noted in the [trigger documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), you can create the trigger from the Edit menu > Current project's triggers. 
[image]

I tested this on a 5-minute interval and received the below outputs. As I manually ran the function the first time, its time value is not consistent with the subsequent iterations.

```
4/6/2018 10:32:15
4/6/2018 10:33:32
4/6/2018 10:38:32
4/6/2018 10:43:32
4/6/2018 10:48:32
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer!
In fact, I tried this, but the problem is that the code is running every 15 minutes. And I want it to trigger after modification of the SpreadSheet. And then wait 15 minutes. The aim is that the personnal informations of the user disappear after 15 minutes.

Comment: Ah! Well that is a different question. Give me a moment to think about it. @Sardinard

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Unfortunately it doesn't work. Probably because I did something wrong. --> I pasted the function on Edit and doSomething. Then I put a trigger "on edit" to the two functions. However nothing seems to happen when I edit the Spreadsheet. I don't understand..  :(  @Diego

Comment: Ok, I'm stupid not to have thought about it! Yet, I tried all afternoon to make it work but it does not react. I'm posting the code I'm trying to run if you would find my mistake it would be so great! :)

Comment: @Sardinard You're not stupid! In fact, I am, because I was wrong when I told you not to create a trigger. You do need to create a trigger for the `doSomething()` function, and have it run every 5 minutes. So sorry for the confusion. _(Copy/paste your new code, create a 5-minute trigger for `doSomething()`, edit something in the document, check the Script Properties to see the `lastTrigger` time, check again in 20 minutes to see that it worked.)_ Careful, the `lastTrigger` time resets **every time** an edit is made to the spreadsheet.

Comment: it works very well! Thank you! I know that I can be annoying but there's just one problem left, if you close the internet browser nothing proceed. If it is not possible to solve this, that's not a big problem, it would remain very cool ^^ @Diego

Comment: @Sardinard You're not annoying. This has been an interesting problem. I don't understand your last problem. I just made an edit to the sheet, then immediately closed the browser. After the 15 minutes elapsed, I opened the browser again, and see that it worked.

Comment: Indeed, I tested again and it works. Sorry, I must have been wrong! In any case, thank you very much for all the help, it really made me happy to be supported by someone talented and friendly! Good continuation! @Diego